# Updating NaN values in specific column in a df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below df
df

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   a   a_1 XYZ
1   b   b_1 XYZ
2   c   c_1 XYZ
3   d   d_1 NaN
4   e   e_1 NaN
5   f   f_1 NaN
```

There are just 2 values in col_3, NaN and XYZ, and I'm trying to update the NaN values to the other value present in the column

the outcome should be this:
df

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   a   a_1 XYZ
1   b   b_1 XYZ
2   c   c_1 XYZ
3   d   d_1 XYZ
4   e   e_1 XYZ
5   f   f_1 XYZ
```

I tried use replace,loc,fillna and others things and none worked, could you guys help me?

Comment: You are looking for `ffill`. `df['col3'].ffill()`

Comment: since you say there will be only 1 value next to None, you can also just assign the whole column to that value. To get the value you can use `set` or `unique` with col3.

Comment: hey @SomeDude I got this error :

NameError: name 'ffill' is not defined

Comment: Sorry @Rabinzel , didn't get you..but yes, the whole column will have only 1 value, which will be the other value different than NaN

Comment: @gfernandes, did you forget to import pandas? here is the [documentation for `.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), so it definitely exists.

Comment: @VladimirFokow not really, I double checked and the piece of code sent by SomeDude didn't work, I will have a look at the documentation you send, thanks

Comment: the ffill is exactly what I was looking for, I checked the doc and saw my mistake...

Answer (score 0):

the ffill is exactly what I was looking for, I checked the doc and saw my mistake...

basically, this :

```
df['col3'].ffill()
```